# Today, without warning, all admin panel logins redirect to home page after login. non-admin users logins work well

Tags: wp-admin, login

(oursite.com)/wp-login.php?itsec-hb-token=(our token)

- all admin logins redirect to the home page (in a logged-in state).
- all admin users are affected.
- non-admin users login works well.
- no code changes have been done. I am the only one allowed to make them. admin
- admin login worked yesterday. today it's not.
- all admin users have the administrator in their capabilities
- temporarily removing the plugins folder has no effect.

we are on AWS/EC-2 running NGINX. It's been running for years. Everything works well, EXCEPT for admin logins, suddenly, without notice and without any change.

what is going on?

Comment: It could be that you've been hacked. Do you have a backup (database and files) you can restore?

Comment: No, not hacked. I figured out what happened. I'll post it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

So, we figured out what it was.

In the `options` table (`wp_options` for some, we chose to do away with the `wp` prefix), there's a `user_roles` (or `wp_user_roles` value). One of the plugins we used (Yoast SEO in this case) had an update that zapped the value of that option, removing the Administrator role from that list. As a result, no admin could log into the admin panel. Once we restored that particular row to its former self -- things started working again.